# PYTHON How to make "associative array"

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I made a python script and need to have some parameters in an XML. So here is the XML  :

```
<ROOT>
<FOLDERTYPES>
    <FOLDERTYPE_ID>
        <NAME>FOURNISSEUR</NAME>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Administratif</NAME>
            <ID>4</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Commandes</NAME>
            <ID>5</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Factures</NAME>
            <ID>6</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
    </FOLDERTYPE_ID>
    <FOLDERTYPE_ID>
        <NAME>CLIENT</NAME>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Administratif</NAME>
            <ID>4</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Commandes</NAME>
            <ID>5</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Factures</NAME>
            <ID>6</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
        <SUBFOLDER>
            <NAME>Logistique</NAME>
            <ID>7</ID>
        </SUBFOLDER>
    </FOLDERTYPE_ID>
</FOLDERTYPES>
```

For now, I'm just capable to get the "name" and "ID" like the following :

```
{'FOURNISSEUR': {'id': '2'}, 'CLIENT': {'id': '3'}}
```

But I need to have all of the subfolders, in a dict like this :

```
{'FOURNISSEUR': {'id': '2', 'subfolders' : {'Administratif':'4','Commandes':'5','Factures':'6'}}, 'CLIENT': {'id': '3', 'subfolders' : {'Administratif':'4','Commandes':'5','Factures':'6','Logistique':'7'}}
```

Here is the piece of code I have for now :

```
def getFolderTypeArray(fileName):
    result = {}
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as config_file:
        content = config_file.read()
    config = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

    folderTypesId = config.find_all('foldertype_id')
    for folderType in folderTypesId:
        label               = folderType.find('name').string
        folderTypeId        = folderType.find('id').string
        result[label]       = {'id' : folderTypeId}
```

Comment: They're called dictionaries or `dict`s in python, not associative arrays. You probably want an xml parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Well, where are you making the subfolder key?

Comment: @cricket_007 for now I didn't code anything for the subfolders. I just made some tries, but without success because I didn't know how to realize that

Comment: check: https://github.com/hay/xml2json

Comment: `result['subfolders'] = some_dictionary` after the loop. Build that inner dictionary within the loop... You're already building a dictionary. `result[label]` and `{'id' : folderTypeId}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in another loop

```
folderTypesId = config.find_all('foldertype_id')
for folderType in folderTypesId:
    label               = folderType.find('name').string
    folderTypeId        = folderType.find('id').string
    subfolders = dict() 
    for s in folderType.find_all('subfolder'):
        subfolders[s.find('name').string] = s.find('id').string
    result[label]       = {'id' : folderTypeId, 'subfolders': subfolders}
```